# remote mysql database connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, centos, remote-access

I can connect to a remote database via application server by command line but unable to connect via PHP application.

It gives me `Can't connect to MySQL server on *.*.*.*` Error.

I added IP in `/etc/hosts` file, added IP and bind-address in `my.cnf` in an Application server, create a new user with application IP and flush privileges in database server but nothing works.

is there any packages missing?, I did install `MySQL-Client` on the application server but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because i don't know your server stack, i assume you install this on VPS.
You can check if mysql library is installed by  create simple info.php with

    <?php phpinfo();?>

check if your php already have mysql module.

don't forget to remove this info.php file after checking the server information.

if not installed, you can try install **php-mysql** module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem to connect to MySQL with the function mysql_connect(...) . After looking around, I figure out that on CentOS there is protection and one of them was blocking the connection.

Ensure that `httpd_can_network_connect_db` is enable (=on).

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd_can_network_connect_db

setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db=on
```

This could be nice in a Wiki section :)

Hope this help folks with the same issue